# How to put a auto delete option in a text field

Tags: iphone

I want to show gray circle with the white x in the right-side of the field which on click will delete the content of the textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. It can be done by setting following property:
aTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

Comment: And in IB, under Text Field attributes, it's Clear Button - Appears While Editing (or other values)